# Проблемы с String.format()

Tags: java

Добрый день. Использую в работе старую версию JAVA а именно 1.4.2
В программе использовал такую вещь как String.format(). Но при попытке компиляции выдает ошибку вида

```
tl.java:25: cannot resolve symbol  
symbol : method format (java.lang.String,int,int)  
location: class java.lang.String  
tl.this.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", t / 60, t % 60));
```

Вопрос - есть ли какие нибудь альтернативы String.format() для JAVA 1.4.2?
**Сам код программы**

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class tl extends JLabel
{
public tl (Timer timer)
{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
}

private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
{
    private volatile int time = -1;

    private Runnable refresher = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            int t = time;
            tl.this.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", t / 60, t % 60));
        }
    };

    public void run ()
    {
        time++;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(refresher);
    }
};

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel timerLabel = new tl(new Timer());
    timerLabel.setFont(new Font(timerLabel.getFont().getFontName(), timerLabel.getFont().getStyle(), 36));
    frame.add(timerLabel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tl.this.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", (int) t / 60, (int)  t % 60));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот только если быть более точным то нужно вот так:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00");  
tl.this.setText(decimalFormat.format(t / 60) + ":" + decimalFormat.format(t % 60));
```